# How repeat background image in div longer then page length?

Tags: css, html, background

## DIV's (longer than page length) background stops repeating

I have HTML webpage with a background image (in a div), a div stretching from the top to the bottom of the page and  in that a div for content... However the DIV's (stretching from the top to bottom) background stops repeating further down the page! (as soon as you scroll down, there is no more background image) Please help!

Here is the CSS:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    background-color: #7e6f7f;
    height: 100%;
}
#bg {
    /*This is the background image for the whole page*/
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#main {
    /*This is the problem div!!!*/
    padding: 0px;
    width: 85%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #d2b9d3;
    background: url(Images/Background_Content.jpg);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: 0% 0%;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    margin: auto;
}
#content {
    /*This is the the div for the content*/
    display: block;
    width: 85%;
    background-color: #e9cfec;
    padding: 0.9375em; /*0.9375em=15px*/
    border: 0.125em solid #867687; /*0.125em=2px*/
    text-align: justify;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px #baa6bd;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px #baa6bd;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px #baa6bd;
}
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Please show us the HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to use `background-repeat` and set it to either `repeat-x`, `repeat-y` or `repeat-both`.

More details can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp).

**EDIT**

Ah, i see now. The #main is 100%, of the browser when it loads. You'll notice that the repeat stops onces you scroll. A simple solution would be to add a `bottom:0` to the #main style. That'll make it stretch to the very bottom. Also, remove the `height: 100%`.

Comment: I just tried that now, but it made no difference...(isn't background-repeat turned on by default?) It does repeat up until you scroll down. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Ahhhh... Here is the link: [link](http://afrikaanstutor.webs.com/Contact_Me.html)

Comment: Damn, that didn't work either... Updated the CSS on the site, no change!

Comment: Remove the `height: 100%` as well.

Comment: Wait, the other pages have changed now?

Comment: That's what a global stylesheet is for. Looks like you need to add in `min-height: 100%` into the #main to make the smaller pages stretch 100%